# How do you center a label inside a div at the middle of a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I've spent quite some time trying to create a calculator-esque design for my simple JavaScript counter, but I can't move the blue screen, represented by a label which displays the value, inside the counter's pink body, which is represented by a div. I want the screen at the middle of the topmost part of the counter. Instead, [I'm getting this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhJtN.png).

In case you can't see my code for whatever reason; my CSS code for the counter_body and counter_label is as follows;

```css
#counter_label{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  background-color: aqua;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}


#counter_body{
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 136);
  border-radius: 5%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  background: rgb(183, 154, 159);
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<label id = "counter_label">0</label>

<div id="counter_body">
  <button type="button" id="increase">Increase</button>
  <button type="button" id="decrease">Decrease</button>
  <button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<p id="counter_output"></p>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, being an absolute newbie coder, but I can't push the blue label into place. Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

Need to add `display: block;` to `<label>`:

```css
#counter_label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
  background-color: aqua;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}


#counter_body{
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 136);
  border-radius: 5%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  background: rgb(183, 154, 159);
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<label id = "counter_label">0</label>

<div id="counter_body">
  <button type="button" id="increase">Increase</button>
  <button type="button" id="decrease">Decrease</button>
  <button type="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<p id="counter_output"></p>
```

#### More information

- [List of HTML tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) - MDN Docs
- [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) - MDN Docs

**In any case, I consider this incorrect: if the function of the `<label>` differs from the names of the `<input>` fields, it is better to use an appropriate tag instead.** In most cases, we use `<div>`, but if you want to provide a heading, then the `<h1>`, etc. tags can also be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Using a label is the incorrect html element to use here. Labels should be paired with the Input tag, [see more details here.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

If you use a different element, such as `<h1-6>`, it'll center properly.